# What are the translation units in OpenSSL?

Tags: makefile, openssl

I am trying to understand the OpenSSL (`1.1.1`) build process. It seems that `./Configure` will generate a file called `configdata.pm` that contains the compiler flags and so on. There is also a `Makefile` that probably contains some useful information. For simplicity, I have enabled `NO_ASM`.

However, how do I know which translation-units go into building `libcrypto` and `libssl`? It seems that grabbing every `.c` file in the `crypto` and `ssl` directories will result in build errors.

How can I extract this information from the build process?

Comment: Tell us what OS you are building on.

Comment: Linux, macOS, Android, iOS. It shouldn't matter though - the configuration step should handle this.

Answer (score 0):

To know which dependencies go into building `libcrypto` and `libssl`, the generated `Makefile` contains all the information you need.

There is a rule for the target called `libcrypto$(SHLIB_EXT_SIMPLE)` that spells out its dependencies and has a recipe for linking all object files into the `crypto` library. In my current build, that recipe contains a line that is about 14,000 character long. The easiest way to find it in your `Makefile` is to search for the expression `-o libcrypto`.

Similarly, for the `ssl` library, the target is called `libssl$(SHLIB_EXT_SIMPLE)` and you can find the recipe by searching for `-o libssl`

Now figuring out how the `Makefile` itself is generated is a different story... As far as I can tell, the information for that is scattered over many `build.info` files in the different subdirectories, for example those under the `crypto` directory, as well as some templates found in the `Configuration` directory. The information gets tied together by several perl scripts.